# PHP Find All Hashtags But No In Link

Tags: php, string

i need to find all hashtags in string but not on link example:

```
#q https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#Vmyx7cyZcKU #q1 #q3 [ I Want to Get only #q, #q1, #q not hashtags in link ]
```

my code:

```
$string = "#q https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#Vmyx7cyZcKU #q1 #q3";
// Link
$string = preg_replace("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $string);
// Hashtag
$hashtag_url = $web_url. "hashtag/\\0";
$string = preg_replace("(\s?#\w+)", "<a href='$hashtag_url'>\\0</a>", $string);
```

See Image What My Code Show !!!

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8IyE.png
```

Comment: Hash in URLs has a specific meaning. Everything after it is called a fragment (other names may apply). They tend not to be sent to the server.

Answer (score 3):

Match all the hashtags outside the URL can be achieved with a regex that matches URLs and discards them, and then matches hastags in all other contexts:

```
'~(?:f|ht)tps?://[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.\~#?&;/=]+(*SKIP)(*F)|#(\w+)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB7dA2/2)

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/QjUrf0):

```
$string = "#q https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#Vmyx7cyZcKU #q1 #q3";
$string = preg_replace("!(?:f|ht)tps?://[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;/=]+(*SKIP)(*F)|#(\w+)!", "<a href='$1'>$0</a>", $string);
echo $string;
```

Feel free to adjust (especially the replacement pattern) as per your needs.

**Details**:

- `(?:f|ht)tps?://[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.\~#?&;/=]+` - the URL matching part (taken from your code)
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs omitting the match and proceeding to the next match from the current index
- `|` - or
- `#(\w+)` - a `#` followed with 1 or more word chars.

To enable `\w` to match Unicode letters, too, add `~u` modifier at the end.

Comment: What about URLs that has another characters, such as, Arabic, Hebrew, etc? In other words, I mean `[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;/=]`

Comment: your code is fine but code find only hashtags not link ?

Comment: This answer just shows how the required result can be obtained. There are lots of URL regex around SO, choose the one you need.

Comment: As for URL matching part you may just use `(?:ht|f)tps?://\S+`

Comment: (?:ht|f)tps?://\S+ is not okay bro not work show me error Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 't'

Comment: I said *URL part* of the regex, not the regex itself.

Comment: If you still need any clarifications or help, let me know. Right now, I answered how to match hashtags outside of links.